# A wave on a vertical rope

Tags: waves, velocity, string, continuum-mechanics

I'm taking a physic class and there is a problem that I'm not sure how to answer. 
It goes as follow: a heavy rope is tied to the ceiling. Someone jerk the rope. How will the speed, the wavelength and the amplitude of the wave change?

Since the tension in the rope is higher when you move up, I have written that the speed of the wave becomes higher. Since Speed = Wavelength • Frequency and that frequency doesn't change, I have said that the wavelength becomes bigger. Finally, I cannot find anything that links the other parameters to the amplitude. Is the amplitude constant despite the changes?